# Fetch Matter-Enabled commissioned devices from Google Smart Home app

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

How we can fetch the list of Matter Enabled Devices in a different Android application from Google Smart Home Application?

Expected usecase-

1. Pair Nest Hub in the Google Home app
2. Commission matter device(Name: MatterTestDevice)
3. Create android app(Name: TestApp)
4. From TestApp fetch MatterTestDevice and get device information

Answer (score 0):

This particular functionality is not currently supported. You can open a feature request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and we can incorporate it on our road map for future developments. You can also try referring to the [Google Home Sample App for Matter](https://github.com/google-home/sample-app-for-matter-android/releases) for examples usages of APIs offered by Google for matter.

Comment: I don't have access to the public issue tracker. Can you please help how I can create an account and raise the feature request?

Comment: Try using the following the link for opening the feature request. https://issuetracker.google.com/